# Problem while uploading csv data into hive table

Tags: hive

Format used in creating hive table[serde property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vPET.png)

My csv data [csv file demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbyo9.png)

**some of the fields of the csv data is having new line character so it is causing problem such as when we select one column from the table the field having newline character " '\n'" split into more than one row.**

cat of csv file[one row data of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKANx.png)

"May 27, 2018",77266157-8b26-46bb-93f0-a1ef20931a,'2124272900300,OD212427213119003000,62029200,Delivered,NON_FBF,BKPE7CPDZ2, ECHO RED1,Black And Red 07171202,FABOK019000001,NA,5,NA,05/27/18,739,674,65,1,739,Jishad ,Jishad ,"NASSCO TILES POYILTHODI TOWER NEAR TAX CHECK POST FAROKE CHUNGAM",,KOZHIKODE,Kerala,673631,"May 27, 2018 15:59:29","May 29, 2018 10:00:00",,FM324875856,10,8,6,0.3,NO row that is causing problem. There is the newline character between NASSCO TILES & POYILTHODI

Expected result [Expected result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjiRy.png)

Actual result [Getting this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFmdi.png)

Help me to load the CSV file data accurately in the hive table also getting the required results

Comment: can you paste the csv data here..i.e cat <csv> file.. sample rows

Comment: some of the fields of the csv data is having new line character so it is causing problem such as when we select one column from the table the field having newline character " '\n'"  split into more than one row.

Comment: pls paste it in the question section

Comment: i have attached the screenshot of every thing in the question sections

Comment: this seems to be a known issue with Hive csv handling. But there are workarounds available - you can format the data to bring the multiline records into single line using perl. After that you can build the hive table on top of it.. Check my answer for the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround to bring the multiline records into a single line using Perl. Please check if this works

```
> nl kislay_stack.dat
     1  "May 27, 2018",77266157-8b26-46bb-93f0-a1ef29f0931a,'21242721311900300,OD212427213119003000,62029200,Delivered,NON_FBF,BKPE7CPYUWYFVD
     2  Z2,PUMA ECHO RED1,Puma Echo Plus 27 L Medium Backpack Black And Red 07171202,FABOK01900002001,NA,5,NA,05/27/18,739,674,65,1,739,Jisha
     3  d ,Jishad ,"NASSCO TILES
     4  POYILTHODI TOWER
     5  NEAR TAX CHECK POST FAROKE CHUNGAM",,KOZHIKODE,Kerala,673631,"May 27, 2018 15:59:29","May 29, 2018 10:00:00",,FMPC0324875856,10,8,6,0.3,NO
     6  "May 28, 2018",77266157-8b26-46bb-93f0-a1ef29f0931a,'21242721311900300,OD212427213119003000,62029200,Delivered,NON_FBF,BKPE7CPYUWYFVD
     7  Z2,PUMA ECHO RED1,Puma Echo Plus 27 L Medium Backpack Black And Red 07171202,FABOK01900002001,NA,5,NA,05/27/18,739,674,65,1,739,Jisha
     8  d ,Jishad ,"NASSCO TILES2
     9  POYILTHODI TOWER
    10  NEAR TAX CHECK POST FAROKE CHUNGAM",,KOZHIKODE,Kerala,673631,"May 27, 2018 15:59:29","May 29, 2018 10:00:00",,FMPC0324875856,10,8,6,0.3,NO
    11  "May 29, 2018",77266157-8b26-46bb-93f0-a1ef29f0931a,'21242721311900300,OD212427213119003000,62029200,Delivered,NON_FBF,BKPE7CPYUWYFVD
    12  Z2,PUMA ECHO RED1,Puma Echo Plus 27 L Medium Backpack Black And Red 07171202,FABOK01900002001,NA,5,NA,05/27/18,739,674,65,1,739,Jisha
    13  d ,Jishad ,"NASSCO TILES3
    14  POYILTHODI TOWER
    15  NEAR TAX CHECK POST FAROKE CHUNGAM",,KOZHIKODE,Kerala,673631,"May 27, 2018 15:59:29","May 29, 2018 10:00:00",,FMPC0324875856,10,8,6,0.3,NO
    16  "May 30, 2018",77266157-8b26-46bb-93f0-a1ef29f0931a,'21242721311900300,OD212427213119003000,62029200,Delivered,NON_FBF,BKPE7CPYUWYFVD
    17  Z2,PUMA ECHO RED1,Puma Echo Plus 27 L Medium Backpack Black And Red 07171202,FABOK01900002001,NA,5,NA,05/27/18,739,674,65,1,739,Jisha
    18  d ,Jishad ,"NASSCO TILES4
    19  POYILTHODI TOWER
    20  NEAR TAX CHECK POST FAROKE CHUNGAM",,KOZHIKODE,Kerala,673631,"May 27, 2018 15:59:29","May 29, 2018 10:00:00",,FMPC0324875856,10,8,6,0.3,NO
> perl -ne ' if ( /^\"\S+ \d+, \d{4}\"/ && $y++) { $x=~s/\n//g;print "$x\n";$x=$_ } else { $x.=$_ } END { $x=~s/\n//g; print "$x\n";} ' kislay_stack.dat | nl
     1  "May 27, 2018",77266157-8b26-46bb-93f0-a1ef29f0931a,'21242721311900300,OD212427213119003000,62029200,Delivered,NON_FBF,BKPE7CPYUWYFVDZ2,PUMA ECHO RED1,Puma Echo Plus 27 L Medium Backpack Black And Red 07171202,FABOK01900002001,NA,5,NA,05/27/18,739,674,65,1,739,Jishad ,Jishad ,"NASSCO TILES POYILTHODI TOWER NEAR TAX CHECK POST FAROKE CHUNGAM",,KOZHIKODE,Kerala,673631,"May 27, 2018 15:59:29","May 29, 2018 10:00:00",,FMPC0324875856,10,8,6,0.3,NO
     2  "May 28, 2018",77266157-8b26-46bb-93f0-a1ef29f0931a,'21242721311900300,OD212427213119003000,62029200,Delivered,NON_FBF,BKPE7CPYUWYFVDZ2,PUMA ECHO RED1,Puma Echo Plus 27 L Medium Backpack Black And Red 07171202,FABOK01900002001,NA,5,NA,05/27/18,739,674,65,1,739,Jishad ,Jishad ,"NASSCO TILES2 POYILTHODI TOWER NEAR TAX CHECK POST FAROKE CHUNGAM",,KOZHIKODE,Kerala,673631,"May 27, 2018 15:59:29","May 29, 2018 10:00:00",,FMPC0324875856,10,8,6,0.3,NO
     3  "May 29, 2018",77266157-8b26-46bb-93f0-a1ef29f0931a,'21242721311900300,OD212427213119003000,62029200,Delivered,NON_FBF,BKPE7CPYUWYFVDZ2,PUMA ECHO RED1,Puma Echo Plus 27 L Medium Backpack Black And Red 07171202,FABOK01900002001,NA,5,NA,05/27/18,739,674,65,1,739,Jishad ,Jishad ,"NASSCO TILES3 POYILTHODI TOWER NEAR TAX CHECK POST FAROKE CHUNGAM",,KOZHIKODE,Kerala,673631,"May 27, 2018 15:59:29","May 29, 2018 10:00:00",,FMPC0324875856,10,8,6,0.3,NO
     4  "May 30, 2018",77266157-8b26-46bb-93f0-a1ef29f0931a,'21242721311900300,OD212427213119003000,62029200,Delivered,NON_FBF,BKPE7CPYUWYFVDZ2,PUMA ECHO RED1,Puma Echo Plus 27 L Medium Backpack Black And Red 07171202,FABOK01900002001,NA,5,NA,05/27/18,739,674,65,1,739,Jishad ,Jishad ,"NASSCO TILES4 POYILTHODI TOWER NEAR TAX CHECK POST FAROKE CHUNGAM",,KOZHIKODE,Kerala,673631,"May 27, 2018 15:59:29","May 29, 2018 10:00:00",,FMPC0324875856,10,8,6,0.3,NO
>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
> select col1,col2 from kislay3

+----------+---------+--+
|   col1   |  col2   |
+----------+---------+--+
| "May 27  |  2018"  |
| "May 28  |  2018"  |
| "May 29  |  2018"  |
| "May 30  |  2018"  |
+----------+---------+--+

> select concat(col1,col2)  from kislay3;

INFO  : OK
+----------------+--+
|      _c0       |
+----------------+--+
| "May 27 2018"  |
| "May 28 2018"  |
| "May 29 2018"  |
| "May 30 2018"  |
+----------------+--+
```

Comment: redirect the perl output to another file. perl ' { ...... } ' > new.csv

Comment: Thank you, It really worked as my data get organised according to my need

Comment: one more thing when i select the date column it leave the year data only  date is print . It treat 2018 as another column data. How to fix it

Comment: you select first 2 columns and then concatenate

Comment: but the thing is date is split into two column due to which the year part is in another column or wrong column how can we merge it or concatenate it